# fallo al insertar datos en php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
                //obtener id usuario 
            session_start();

            $email = $_SESSION['usuario_email'];
            $nombreUsuario = $_SESSION['usuario_nombre'];
            $apellidoUsuario = $_SESSION['usuario_apellido'];
            $telefono = $_SESSION['usuario_telefono'];

            //echo $email . ' ' . $nombreUsuario . ' ' . $apellidoUsuario . ' ' . $telefono;

            $sql_id = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre='$nombreUsuario' and apellido='$apellidoUsuario' and telefono=$telefono";

            //subir a la base de datos
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conexion);

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql_id)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed! Fallooo";
            }else{
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $idUsuario = $row['id_usuario'];
                }
            }
```

Y me da el siguiente fallo

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()

He estado rompiendome la cabeza en varias web y lo unico que leo es el tema de los drivers, pero la web esta subida al servidor del instituto por lo que no puedo hacer ningun cambio de este tipo. Los datos de nombre, apellido y demás lo he comprobado y están correctamente, el caso es que no me funciona esa funcion. Las demás son de mysqli también y no me han dado error, por lo que busco arreglar esto o que me propongais otra funcion que realize lo mismo que esta.. Agradeceria un monton quien me ayudase. Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo muy claro de cómo usar la sentencia que te está dando error: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: Como sugerencia, si puedes hacer un `phpinfo();` subiendo un script con esa única instrucción, puedes verificar si tienes el driver mysqlnd. Si está, en el apartado de la sección mysqli deberías poder ver algo así:
Client API library version mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $

Si no está instalado, y no puedes instalarlo por no ser el administrador, tienes dos opciones: volver "hacia atrás" usando la extensión mysql (no te lo aconsejo) o tirar hacia delante, pasándote a PDO.